# Reading File Paths from Folder & Sub-Folders into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, directory, filepath, subdirectory

I'm using the following code to read file names into an Excel sheet but I'd like to include sub-folders and capture the entire file path. I've tried a few things but none have worked. I have cobbled this together from pieces of other people's code edited to function in my situation, unfortunately this means my understanding isn't as thorough as it should be.

The files are audio files (wav or mp3), the rest of the spreadsheet will contain metadata which will be used to tag the files: artist, title, album etc.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetFileNames()
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$
InitialFoldr$ = "C:\"

 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
 .Title = "Please select the folder to list audio files from"
 .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
 .Show

  If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
  xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
  xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
  Do While xFname$ <> ""
  Worksheets("Metadata").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
  ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = xFname$
  xRow = xRow + 1
  xFname$ = Dir
  Loop

   Dim x&
    With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            Rows.Hidden = False
            Rows.Hidden = True
        For x = 1 To Rows.Count
            If .WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(x)) > 0 Then Rows(x).Hidden = False
        Next x
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

   Worksheets("Metadata").Visible = True
   Worksheets("Menu").Visible = False

End If
End With
End Sub
```

I'm very new to VBA but am beginning to get a grip on parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

This code will extract all mp3s from a folder and all its subfolders.  Good luck with the VBA!

```
Public Sub FindFiles()
'you must add a reference to 'Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation'

Dim shl As Shell32.Shell
Dim fol As Shell32.Folder
Dim row As Long

Set shl = New Shell32.Shell
Set fol = shl.Namespace("E:\CDs\")
row = 1

ProcessFolderRecursively fol, row

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFolderRecursively(fol As Shell32.Folder, ByRef row As Long)

Dim item As Shell32.FolderItem
Dim fol2 As Shell32.Folder

If Not fol Is Nothing Then
    For Each item In fol.Items
        If item.IsFolder Then
            Set fol2 = item.GetFolder
            ProcessFolderRecursively fol2, row
        Else
            'you might need to edit the criterion here
            If item.Type = "MP3 Format Sound" Then
                Cells(row, 1) = item.Path
                row = row + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want it to only find mp3s, it needs to show me everything in the folders, it could be a mixture of mp3s, wavs, aiffs, wmas etc etc. It works perfectly as is for the root folder & file names, I just want it to be slightly more flexible by looking in sub-folders & returning file paths instead of names. I can always trim the paths if I find I only need file names.

Comment: Just remove the 'If item.Type = ...' line and the corresponding End If below it and it will extract all files in all subfolders

Comment: If this answers your question then could you please mark it as answered.  Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, perhaps I am inserting it in my code in the wrong place. I can't get the results in the same way as my existing code. The current code is perfect as long as there are no sub-folders, it puts the information I want where I want. If there are sub-folders I need a file path so that I know what files are where, I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that I needed only minor adjustment to my existing code.

Comment: Your example uses the Dir function to get the next file that matches the search criteria.  All well and good, but it doesn't work so well when you try and nest/recursively use it to look into an arbitrary depth of subfolders because the Dir function gets 'reset' by each successive call to it if you provide it with arguments (i.e. a new subfolder).  My example pops the values in the first column starting in the first row.  Change the row = 1 line to row = 2 to start it there instead of row 1.  Try stepping through the code (F8) to get a feel for how it works and then have a go at editing it.